# How to capture datasource name when using Azure Search indexer

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a multi-tenant index in azure search and I want to populate it with several indexers, each uploading data from one specific tenant.

I want the search to be filtered by a field "tenantid". Each database that an indexer uses as a data source has the "tenantid" as it's name, but there is no function or option I found that enables adding a custom field mapping the name of the database to a field in the search results.

The naive solution to the problem is to add a field in each document in the DB containing the field "tenantid", but I would rather take this info from the database name and reduce my object size.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no such field mapping function available. Please add this suggestion on [Azure Search UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

To workaround, instead of adding the database name to each document, you can just include it by specifying a datasource query as follows:

```
SELECT c.id, c._ts, 'my_database' AS database FROM collection c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark
```