# Azure Search: Indexer from Cosmos DB DataSource with default values

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have multiple indexers on an index. In the index, I have the fields "sourceDisplayName" and "category".

Two of my indexers are connected to one datasource each, which are both a cosmos db container. One is called "Articles" and one is called "Events". Works fine so far.

Now I want the fields "sourceDisplayName" and "category" in the datasource "Articles" to be always "My Site" and "Article", and for the datasource "Events" to be always "My Site" and "Event".

Is there any way to accomplish this or do I need to insert the values into each cosmos db document using a trigger or stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be done using a skillset to enrich the documents read from Cosmos DB before they are added to the index. However, an even simpler approach for your case could be to add the field to your query in the datasource definition, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119979/how-to-capture-datasource-name-when-using-azure-search-indexer). HTH!